# Como puedo insertar datos a un campo blob usando myBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

Desde mi aplicativo java estoy tratando de insertar utilizando myBatis para poder insertar caracteres demasiados largos a un campo blob, pero al correr mi aplicacion tengo un error.

Este es el query para hacer el insert:

```
<parameterMap type="pe.com.test.model.RequerimientoJson" id="registrarJsonIN"/> 
    <insert id="registrarJson" parameterMap="registrarJsonIN" keyProperty="id">
        <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
        SELECT ${schema}.SQ_SERVICIOJSON.NEXTVAL  FROM DUAL
        </selectKey>  
    INSERT INTO ${schema}.REQ_SERVICIOJSON (ID,REQID,NUMERO,CREACION, REQJSONTEST)
    VALUES (#{id}, #{requerimiento},#{numero}, #{fecha}, #{reqjson}) 
    </insert>
```

El campo de tipo blob es el RESJSONTEST.

El error que tengo es el siguiente:
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: sólo puede enlazar un valor LONG para insertarlo en una columna LONG

#### The error may exist in "/D:/VBRYANDC/Servidores/Jboss-7.2.0/standalone/deployments/TESTRest.ear/test-rest-aso.war/WEB-INF/classes/pe/com/test/dao/RequerimientoMapper.xml"

#### The error may involve pe.com.test.dao.RequerimientoMapper.registrarJsonIN

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [1461]; ORA-01461: sólo puede enlazar un valor LONG para insertarlo en una columna LONG
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: sólo puede enlazar un valor LONG para insertarlo en una columna LONG

Alguien tiene algun ejemplo de como podria insertar utilizando myBatis.

Answer (score 1):

para poder insertar en un campo de tipo clob o blob, el tipo de dato debe ser byte[], pero por algun motivo (que desconozco) no puedes pasar el byte[] como parametro, tiene que se parte de un objeto.

ademas intenta insertar en la clase java.

te muestro un ejemplo de como lo tengo yo.

```
public class Documento implements Serializable{

    private String nombre;
    private TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;
    private String orden;
    private String archivoBase64;
    private byte[] archivo;

}
```

acorte un poco el objecto tiene mas atributos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO docPatofer(id_dctosa, id_acred, nombre, archivo, contenttype, id_tipo_archivo, numero_archivo) " + 
        " VALUES (sequence.nextval, #{idAcreditacion}, #{nombre}, #{archivo}, #{contentType}, #{tipoDocumento.idTipoDocumento}, #{numeroArchivo})")
public Integer insertaDocumentoAcreditacion(Documento documento);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No se ve la clase `pe.com.test.model.RequerimientoJson` pero deduzco que el campo `reqjson` lo has declarado como Long. Debe ser `byte[]`.

```
public class RequerimientoJson {

    private byte[] reqjson;
    // resto de campos

    // getters & setters
}
```

Y luego en el mapper:

```
INSERT INTO ${schema}.REQ_SERVICIOJSON (ID,REQID,NUMERO,CREACION, REQJSONTEST)
    VALUES (#{id}, #{requerimiento},#{numero}, #{fecha}, #{reqjson.bytes,jdbcType=BINARY})
```

Modifico solo `reqjson`, asumo que el resto de campos están bien.

Tampoco sabemos cómo está definida la columna **REQJSONTEST** en la tabla **REQ_SERVICIOJSON** pero nos imaginamos que es algo como **BLOB**.

Prueba y ya nos contarás.

Saludos